Imgur image can be loaded in <img> the but not directly in a new browser tab
Here's an example image that I can view with no problem: https://imgur.com/K592dul.jpg. I can point to this in my <img> tags and have it be loaded on webpages, as well as right click on desktop (or long press on mobile) and select "open image in new tab" without problem.
However, depending on the size of the image and screen it's being viewed on, I may choose to append a suffix to the image ID as detailed here in order to load smaller resized images to significantly save on bandwidth and page loading speeds. For example, the above link could become: https://imgur.com/K592dulm.jpg where that last 'm' is added for a smaller resolution.
The problem is that I'm only able to see this second "resized" link when embedded on my webpages. I'm not able to "open in new tab" or view it in any other way. Is there something wrong I'm doing here or is it possible to override what gets loaded when "open in new tab is selected"?

It's unlikely that you'll be able to intercept and change the behaviour. Even responsive images wouldn't help, since they're based on the viewport size, not the container size. Could you wrap the image in a link pointing to the higher-resolution version instead?

@Richard I tried wrapping the images in  tags and it did give the option to "open link in new tab" but the image options also remain with the issue :/ How is it even possible that the content exists and can be retrieved when embedded in an  tag but then not accessible when independently loaded?
